# Memory leak detectors

Tags: c#, c++, memory-leaks

I am reading a few articles on memory leaks. I came across some of the tools like:

1. perfmon+debugdiag which is default windows tool
2. Sleepy
3. AMD code analyst
4. Including a debug_new in a stadx.h file for C++
5. wingdb with SOS dll
6. also some paid tools.

I wanted to know if `perfmon`+`debugdiag` is enough to detect all the memory leaks?. Or are there other tools that are better in some cases. I wanted to know when to use what.

Suppose I have a C# application which calls 3rd party unmanaged dll. How do I find the leak in the 3rd party DLL ?

Comment: Even if we assume the tool you use to detect memory leaks is perfect, it will never be able to detect *all* of them. What you're essentially asking for is a solution to the halting problem.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/02/588350.aspx

Comment: @quantumSoup, could you explain that more thoroughly? If he reproduces all use cases of his software, which case wouldn't the tool reach?

Comment: @Spidey That's a pretty big if. But yes, *if* you can do that, sure.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a pretty big if, but I was afraid there was some odd cases I should be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool by far I have used so far for this task is the [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/).

Comment: But again, you need to know something about your application so you know what to look for

Comment: .net memory profiler is only for managed leaks i guess.

Answer (score 1):

A very good tool for this purpose is Red Gate's ANTS Memory Profiler: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/features/

I have succesful used it only for managed DLLs, but it can profile COM+ applications too.